# How do I prompt users to insert Drive letter in Batch-File file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a working simple `batch-file` program which unhides predefined drive hidden folders.
What I want to do is:
To insert Drive letter by a user instead of predefined and other option if you suggested me.

my unhide.bat code is:

```
@echo off
D:
attrib -r -s -h /s /d
pause
```

Comment: please why you downvote instead of helping problems of peoples.

Comment: @ t3chb0t no need to say for questions simple. Because peoples may be confused with it.

Comment: stack Overflow is not a place where only sophisticated questions is asked, but also simple and moderate.

Comment: Google is machine expert, but I need human being Expert.

Comment: If wading through Google's search results is too difficult for you, I'd start putting as much time as humanly possible in to learning how to search because `set`, `echo`, and `pause` are the three commands that you have to know to even be considered a beginner, and it only gets more complicated from there. I highly recommending reading the `help` output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `set /p DriveLetter=Please enter drive letter.`.  If you then run `%DriveLetter%` as a command, it will expand as you expect.

To make your code work:

```
@echo off
set /p DriveLetter=Please enter drive letter.
%DriveLetter%
attrib -r -s -h /s /d
pause
```

They would enter "`D:`" and it would accept it as such.

The only thing to note is that if someone uses an incorrect drive letter, bad stuff will happen.

Alternatively, you could use a large block with [`CHOICE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732504.aspx), but that seems overkill.  You'd have to define every drive letter.  Thus, I won't go into detail on this.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
SET /P letter=Please give your drive letter and press ENTER: 
ECHO %letter%
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you try to unhide the folders into the USB Drive caused by a worm

If you like to detect the drive letter of your USB Key, Try this code instead,

I made this tool to unhide folders and files and delete all infected links into the USB key

```
@echo off
Mode con cols=98 lines=10 & Color 9E
Title Searching the Drive letter of your USB Key by Hackoo 2014
echo.
ECHO   *******************************************************************************************
echo.
echo                           Searching the drive letter of your USB Key .......
echo.
ECHO   *******************************************************************************************
wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID,DriveType /Format:CSV > %Tmp%\tmp.txt 
for /f "skip=2 tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in ('%COMSPEC% /a /c type "%Tmp%\tmp.txt"') do echo %%b %%c >> %Tmp%\tmp2.txt
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('%COMSPEC% /a /c type "%Tmp%\tmp2.txt" ^|Find "2"') Do (set MyUSBDrive=%%i)
Del %Tmp%\tmp.txt & Del %Tmp%\tmp2.txt
cls
echo.
ECHO   *******************************************************************************************
echo.
echo                          The drive letter of your USB Key is  %MyUSBDrive%
echo.
ECHO   *******************************************************************************************
pause
cls
echo.
echo.
ECHO   *******************************************************************************************
echo.
echo      Press a button to delete infected shortcuts and restore hidden files in your USB key
echo.
ECHO   *******************************************************************************************
pause>nul
cls
echo.
echo.
ECHO   *******************************************************************************************
echo.
echo            Deleting infected shortcuts and restoring hidden files
echo.
ECHO   *******************************************************************************************
:: To Unhide Folders and files into your USB key
Attrib -s -h -r %MyUSBDrive%\*.* /D /S >nul 2>&1
:: To delete all infected files.lnk
Del %MyUSBDrive%\*.lnk >nul 2>&1
Explorer %MyUSBDrive%
pause
```

Comment: Actually, using `attrib` to hide/unhide folders was extremely common a few years ago, and the code in the question looks very similar to [locker.bat](http://www.howtogeek.com/105633/how-to-create-a-password-protected-folder-without-any-extra-software/).